# Show the Selenium browser window always on top

Tags: java, selenium, cmd, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a project using Selenium and ChromeDriver.

I want to know if there is a way to ensure the Selenium browser window is always displayed on top of other windows, similar to what is possible with JFrames.

So far I didn't find any solution. The only things I found were to give the window focus, but I don't want to do that.

I thought of maybe there is a way to do it through the `cmd`, but I don't know much about that.

Comment: I believe it is always displayed on top by default , doesn't it  ?

Comment: it is displayed on top as long as it has the focus. As in the normal Jframe configurations. But JFrame has a setting where you can let the frame be visible all the time also if you use another window. But I want to do that with selenium